# There has been a critical error on this website whenever I try to install the budyboss plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Everytime I install and active a plugin on WordPress it shows me "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site's admin email inbox for instructions" this message. I've tried to install and active the Buddyboss and elementor plugin that happens. It doesn't happen when I install the plugin. It occurres when I active the plugin. How can I solve this?

Comment: Enable the debug log, then check its contents to see what the actual problem is. See [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Buddyboss and Elementor both the plugins and activated, could not face any issues. Could you please change the theme and try again? It may sometimes caused by the activated theme. I suggest you to switch to default WordPress theme(twenty twenty two) and check. Another thing can be caused by the PHP version, please check your PHP version, I am using PHP 8+ and it is perfectly working.

*Make sure you have only these two plugins activated when you are checking to avoid any kind of conflict. Best of luck.